# Can't maintain the dynamic dropdown selected value after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, dynamic-controls

Am using the below code to create a multiple drop down list. But i can't able to maintain the previous selected value. Please help me to maintain the previous vaues.

My code is Here:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
        {
            Session["i"] = Count;

            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "lbl" + i;
            lbl.Text = "Head";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));

            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "ID" + i;
            ddl.DataValueField = "fld_Head";
            ddl.DataTextField = "fld_Head";
            ddl.DataSource = DVS;
            ddl.DataBind();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);
        }
```

Comment: The above code is present in a button click event

Comment: What happens when you click the button?

Comment: The new controls created in the second row and clear the previous selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928524/property-null-after-postback-dynamically-loaded-control/10929096#10929096) you should init values of you dynamic controls in `Page_Init` event.

Because asp.net internal functionality working with viewstate populates values in `Page_Load` event and if your dynamic control isn't still created it's values are ignored.\

Common issue =)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a `DropDownList` dynamically to a `Panel`. Newly added `DropDownList` control will not be available at a post-back. You can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ID" + i]
```

to get the values from post request. And with that values you can add new controls with new state.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the creation of dynamic controls in Page_Init works perfectly.