# Method being triggered on page load but not via asp button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have two asp:Labels, the first of which is replaced with a few buttons and the second with a list of items.

I want to click on the buttons to filter the items.

The contents of the buttons are added programmatically by replacing the text with html and works fine.

asp:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Label id="filters" runat="server" Text="Filters here"/>
  <asp:Label id="itemList" runat="server" Text="List of items here"/>
</form>
```

resultant html of filters label:

```
<input type="submit" onclientclick="Load_Items(0)" runat="server" value="First"/>
<input type="submit" onclientclick="Load_Items(1)" runat="server" value="Second"/>
<input type="submit" onclientclick="Load_Items(2)" runat="server" value="Third"/>
```

relevant c#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Load_Items(0);
  }
}
public void Load_Items(int filterType)
{
  //code to load items (pseudo below)
  for each row in list
    if filterType = itemType
      build string
  replace second label with string
}
```

On page load everything happens just as I want it to with the contents being filtered by the first item (hence `Load_Items(0)`), and if I manually change the 0 to another number in Page_Load, it filters by the other types, but if I click the buttons which are programmatically added, nothing happens other than what looks like the page refreshing.

I know the post back check is working by adding a text replacement before and inside it.

I've also added an asp:button to make sure it's not something to do with the way the buttons are added as below (with some extra things recommended from searches):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclientclick="Load_Items(2); return false;" text="Submit" />
```

So what could be the issue?

Comment: I do not see where the buttons you created trigger Load_Items(). How should that work?

Comment: @KaiHartmann - My bad, copy pasting error.

Comment: That won't work, because your buttons just call a method on client side, not the one on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`OnClientClick` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) specifies the javascript to run in the browser when the button is clicked. Since you probably don't have a javascript function called `Load_Items`, this will generate a script error, and the button will then cause the form to post back.

The server-side [`Click` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) will fire on the server, but doesn't allow you to pass a parameter. You will only get the button instance and an empty `EventArgs` instance.

You might be better off using the [`Command` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx), combined with the [`CommandArgument` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx).

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument="2" OnCommand="Load_Items" ...
```

The event handler would use the `CommandArgument` property of the `CommandEventArgs` to access the argument from the clicked button:

```
protected void Load_Items(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Load_Items(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
}
```

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have used OnClientClick, but when searching so many things at once I lost track. Haven't used OnCommand before. Works like a charm right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the common problem which I think every asp.net developer deals some time. The common part of it, that asp.net event system doesn't work, as windows forms.
 `Page` object, and all controls on that page, have [lifecycle events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), that are triggered during any request, even when it's from update panel.
 As you create those controls by code, you have to keep in mind, that all events for those controls should work as part of `Page` object. That's why you have to create those object in `Page_Init` event, before all other control's event would  be triggered.
 Please also keep in mind that you have to create those controls as asp.net objects:

```
var btn = new Button();
```

But not by simply adding html markup. And you have to recreate them on each request, following that one, when they were created.

Please take a look on my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928524/property-null-after-postback-dynamically-loaded-control/10929096#10929096).

Comment: Well the filtering works with the hard coded button, but not with programmatically html like you say. I'll have to look into how to create the buttons.