# How to create an asp:button programmatically in c# behind (without click handling)

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, aspbutton

The following button provides the exact functionality I require, but it must be done programmatically as I will be making more than one based on some variables, but the latter I can figure out if I can just create the button below as a starter:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnCommand="Load_Items" CommandArgument="1" text="Submit" />
```

More information on what I've been doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884044/method-being-triggered-on-page-load-but-not-via-asp-button/).

Edit:

I have looked at questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188007/creating-an-aspbutton-programatically), but don't see where to go from `Button btnSave = new Button();` to seeing a button on the page. Also, most questions I've found seem to go about using C# to handle clicking, but I want to have an OnCommand property to handle it.

If I do the following and search using the developer tools for "btn", I get no results.

```
Button btnSave = new Button();
btnSave.ID = "btnSave";
btnSave.Text = "Save";
btnSave.CssClass = "btn";
```

Comment: So, what search terms have you used so far to research this?

Comment: You have the "this is what I want" part, but what about the "this is what I have done so far" part? And why can't you just make a button in code?

Comment: I can't make a button because I don't know how, hence my question. I have edited the OP to add some clarification on previous searches and how this is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you create a Button with Command event.

Once it is created, you need to find a way of displaying it. The following example uses  `PlaceHolder`; you can also substitute with `Panel` if you want.

### ASPX

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            ID = "Button" + i,
            CommandArgument = i.ToString(),
            Text = "Submit" + i
        };
        button.Command += Load_Items;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}

private void Load_Items(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    // Do something with id
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, and it does indeed work, the only issue is this assumes the number of buttons is known, but the reason I am creating them programmatically is that it may vary. Any tips?

Comment: I tried programmatically adding placeholders based on the number of buttons and then replacing those but it sounds horrible and doesn't work.

Comment: Just create a panel at desgin time, and add all the programmatically created buttons to this single panel. I don't know, but you should be able to do that even with the placeholder control. Do not replace anything, just add the buttons to it.

Comment: @dudledok Kai's comment is correct. You need a Panel or a PlaceHolder at design time. (Or you can add controls directly to `form` control, but I do not like that approach.) I updated my answer to display multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container control on your page. Try an asp panel for example. Then in your codebehind you do panel.controls.add(btnSave); And don't forget to do it on every site load. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515/en-us